# Problem in file upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

whenever i am uploading trying to upload file having size more than the size specified in maxRequestLength , browser is showing "webpage can not be displayed" .
an someone please tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Increase `maxRequestLength` value in your `web.config` file.

> `maxRequestLength` indicates the
>   maximum file upload size supported by
>   ASP.NET. This limit can be used to
>   prevent denial of service attacks
>   caused by users posting large files to
>   the server. The size specified is in
>   kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4
>   MB).

See [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN.

So, if e.g. the page you posted a file is `Upload.aspx`, the necessary section in `web.config` would be like this

```
<location path="Upload.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="{your value here}" 
                     executionTimeout="{your value here}" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your web.config

```
  <system.web>
     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" maxRequestLength="100000" />
```

That enables a 360 second timeout and 100,000 Kb of upload data at a time.

If that doesn't work, run this command on your IIS server. (replace [IISWebsitename])

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "[IISWebsitename]" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:100000000 -commitpath:apphost
```

That enables 100,000,000 bytes of upload data at a time.